# compiler is giving me an error: no match for 'operator*'

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I am a newbie student taking cse 100 any help understanding this topic is appreciated.
It was compiling fine but when run it was prompting user only once, after several changes the teacher suggested now the program doesn't compile. It gives me following errors.

```
main.cpp|30|error: no match for 'operator*' (operand types are 'const double' and 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}')|

main.cpp|33|error: no match for 'operator*' (operand types are 'const double' and 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}')| 

main.cpp|36|error: no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' and 'double')|
```

Attempted code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const double adultTicket = 9.50; //declared const double with value of
    //$9.50price per adult ticket.
    const double childTicket = 6.50; //declared const double with value
    //of $6.050 per child ticket.

    cout << "Please enter movie name \n"; //User prompt to enter movie name.
    string movName;
    getline(cin,movName); //Declared variable told name entered by user.

    cout << "Please enter number of Adult tickets sold \n"; //User prompt to
    //enter amounnt of adult tickets sold.
    string adultTicketsSold;
    getline(cin, adultTicketsSold); //Declared variable that holds number of
    //adult tickets sold.

    cout << "Please enter number of children tickets sold \n"; //User prompt
    //to enter number of children tickets sold.
    string childTicketsSold;
    getline(cin,childTicketsSold); // Declared variable to hold number of
    //child tickets sold.

    string grossAdult;
    grossAdult = adultTicket*adultTicketsSold;

    double grossChild;
    grossChild = childTicket*childTicketsSold;

    double grossBox;
    grossBox = grossAdult+grossChild;

    double distributorTake;
    distributorTake = grossBox*0.80;

    double netBox;
    netBox = grossBox*0.20;

    cout << "Revenue Report" <<endl;
    cout << "Movie name:" << movName <<endl;
    cout << "Adult Tickets Sold:" << adultTicketsSold <<endl;
    cout << "Child Tickets Sold:" << childTicketsSold <<endl;
    cout << "Gross Box Office Profit: $" << grossBox <<endl;
    cout << "Amount Paid to Distributor: $" << distributorTake <<endl;
    cout << "Net Box Office Profit: $" << netBox <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Those compiler errors mean you are using an operator (e.g. `*`) on two types that don't have that operator defined between them (e.g. `std::string` and `double`; `0.5 * "hello world"` doesn't make sense!). Look through your code, and find the places you've made that mistake.

Answer (score 3):

The problems are with these lines, you're trying to multiply a `std::string` by a `double`, instead of multiplying two `double` together.

```
grossAdult = adultTicket*adultTicketsSold;
```

You can convert the `std::string` to a `double` using [`std::stod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof)

```
grossAdult = adultTicket * std::stod(adultTicketsSold);
```

Or if you prefer you can just accept a `double` as input instead of doing the conversion

```
cout << "Please enter number of Adult tickets sold \n";
double adultTicketsSold;
cin >> adultTicketsSold;
```

Comment: For future readers: `stod` can throw, and at some point for some reason your call to it will throw, and you'll wish you had a `try...catch`

Comment: @AndyG Good suggestion. And on that note it would be worth checking the stream after the `cin` alternative too, in case they entered a non-numeric value you could check `cin.good()`.